# Multi bar chart using NVD3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to create a multibar chart using NVD3.js. All the example are showing bars belongs to the same Y1-Axis. I need to show bar1 for Y1-Axis and bar2 for Y2-axis.

Is it possible? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with NVD3 as it's built for re-usability. You could try drawing multiple bar charts alongside each other or try using pure d3.

Have not done/tried stuff like this.

If you manage to find a solution, please do share your solution. It's interesting.

### Update

Have you noticed how the charts in the [NVD3 homepage](http://nvd3.org/) work. All 4 charts change based on the selection of categories on the MultiBarChart legend. You could try something similar.

Comment: Can you give me the example, A NVD3 multiBarChart with Focus chart?

Comment: Does the updated comment make any sense, thats the only example I have.